# Does AWS SQS guarantee the order of array elements in its payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, message-queue, amazon-sns

I have a a SNS topic and then there is a SQS which subscribes to it. Let us say I publish a message with a simple payload

```
{
  ids: [1,3,7,2,8]
}
```

Is it always guaranteed that I will receive the message from SQS without any changes to the position of the elements compared to the original published payload?

```
// not possible
{
  ids: [1,2,3,7,8]
}
```

If not, how can I ensure that the elements in the array would be received in the same order as it was published?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The payload is simply a value that you created and serialized into the message. SQS does not know or care about the payload. In the example above, the order of ids will be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A message is **simply a string** that is passed through to the payload.

Amazon SQS and Amazon SNS will not modify the payload. It doesn't even know that it's JSON.